# offload media to external services

Tags: images, plugin-recommendation, post-thumbnails, media-library

Does anyone know a way (plugins or similar) to offload media (images mostly) in wordpress to an external service? like flicker, or imageshak?

I think that offloading images from the wordpress installation increase significantly the mante the maintainability of your site, and not mentioning the speeding up of the backupping process!

One sad note is that many themes need the images on the same server to create thumbnails for post previews, while I thinks a better approach would be to create temporary made up files of the images.

thanks!

Comment: Typically you want to use a real CDN like Amazon or Rackspace for this, there are several plugins, hopefully someone knows more about good integrations.

Comment: but if i'm not wrong, CDN don't work like a file management system, but spawn your files around the world for a faster access, isn't it? (BTW they are not free :) )

Comment: Sort of, the term has become a bit loose, I was referring to the storage aspect of a CDN which can be used for network delivery or just as storage, have a look at amazon S3 or Rackspace cloud files (there are others).

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-methods-host-wordpress-blog-images-external-server/

Comment: @Bakaburg did you find anything good?

Comment: eh sincerely, so much time has passed that I totally forgot what I did eventually!

Comment: @Bakaburg indeed, it's been a while! I just wrote an answer, as I think I found a couple of interesting solutions http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209654/84030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the following plugins that use an external storage for media. Some of them supposedly use the build in media (S3), while other simply allow you to use the storage in your post (azure) via a button.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/windows-azure-storage/ , yes Microsoft wrote this plugin.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-s3-cloudfront/ Amazon S3 for WordPress.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cdn-sync-tool/  Several services(cloudfiles, s3, maxcdn, etc)
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pressbox/  Dropbox

The tag on WordPress which has more options: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/s3

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a service like CloudFlare?  They are free and work as much more than just a CDN, also providing added security and bulletproof DNS services.  VERY easy to get going, and once you do, the image caching, CDN, minification of JS and CSS, etc... is all automatic.

I've been using them since they first started the service and it's been absolutely stellar for me and many of my clients.

Comment: we already use it, but the question was different :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option - wpengine.com have a pretty stellar repulation as a dedicated WordPress hosting company and they recently released what promises to be seamless [integration with Amazon S3](http://wpengine.com/2012/08/02/unlimited-storage-with-wp-engines-proprietary-largefs/) for large storage needs. It *might* be the best of both worlds.

I'm not affiliated in any way - but I am thinking of trying it myself.

Comment: Chris Lema is also recommending S3 Media Maestro plugin: http://chrislema.com/use-amazon-s3-with-wordpress-to-host-private-videos/

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this in as an option I didn't see listed above... W3 Total Cache (link below).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

I use this because it has a wide range of CDNs it supports, including a generic setting, and will also take care of offloading media files, theme files and other core files that don't necessarily need to be served from the same webserver.

You can also define custom directories to be offloaded to your CDN if you are need something stored offsite that doesn't fall within the normal WP file structure.

Comment: This does not mean that the images are permanently hosted somewhere else. I believe your answer is not directly relevant, although w3tc seems to provide good caching and CDN services.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking into hosting my Wordpress blog's images in a third party service, and have a plugin helping me seamlessly integrate this strategy.

I found these options:

- **WP Imgur plugin**, [wordpress.org/plugins/wp-imgur](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-imgur) and [github.com/dsawardekar/wp-imgur](https://github.com/dsawardekar/wp-imgur): synchronizes your wordpress pictures with imgur
- **S3 + Cloudfront**: Amazon S3 (not free) will not be a media manager per se but it will host medias on their super fast servers. On top of that, CloudFront will be used as a CDN to make things even faster. More of a enterprise solution really. [elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-with-wordpress](http://elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-with-wordpress)

That's the only solutions that get any close to what I was looking for. But maybe there are others, please post a comment if you find another one!